# Nesting classes with Typescript

Tags: android, typescript, typescript1.8

How do you include a class in a class in Typescript? I am trying to model the android APIs, to use in nativescript, so I need to declare a class ina  class in a module, as shown below:

```
export module myModule {    
    export class MasterClass {

        static myVariable: number;

        public static myFunction(param: string): boolean;

        static class myClass2{
            someFunction():void;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this throws all sorts of errors, e.g.

> error TS1005: '=' expected.

and if I do something like:

```
myClass = Class {}
```

Then I get compiler errors shouting about not being allowed initialisers in ambient contexts.

How can I do this, such that `tsc` is happy and I can reference `myModule.MasterClass.myClass2.somefunction()`. ?

Comment: `myModule.MasterClass.myClass2.somefunction()` only makes sense if `somefunction` is static

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in typescript, it's not equivalent to java.

In java inner classes are part of the instance of their parent class, and static inner classes basically only use their parent class as a namespace/closure, and you can imitate that in typescript with a `namespace`:

```
export module myModule {
    export namespace MyNamespace {
        export var myVariable: number;
        export function myFunction(param: string): boolean {}

        export class MasterClass {}

        export class MyClass2 {
            someFunction(): void {}
        }
    }
}
```

So all of the static members/methods are now namespace variables/functions and you can reference then using the dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge class and namespace:

```
export namespace MyModule {
    export class MasterClass {
        public myVariable: number;
        public static myFunction(param: string): boolean {
            return false;
        }
    }
    export namespace MasterClass {
        export class myClass2 {
            public static someFunction(): void {
                // implementation
            }
        }
    }
}

MyModule.MasterClass.myClass2.someFunction();
```

PS. You should avoid `module` keyword. Use `namespace` instead.